# Why do I need Nginx to run Tornado Web Server (python)

Tags: nginx, python, tornado

Maybe this is a stupid question. So stupid that I can't find the answer in tutorials or documentation.

I want to make some tests with Tornado Web Server. As far as I can see in the examples, Tornado can be started in, for instance, port 8000 and this setup is made with python code in the root of the app.

However, I've seen that people seems to be using it with Nginx, and I don't understand well their motivations. I understand that having an Nginx in the front can be necessary for production purposes, but for debugging, Isn't enough to start the script with the application?:

```
python app.py
```

Why is necessary to have Nginx even for testing purposes?. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really. Some configurations just take use of nginx's very good caching.
Others just follow cargo cult engineering. Some are doing well because
it solves their problem.

It's also mandatory to have a testing environment that reflects your production.

Comment: `It's also mandatory to have a testing environment that reflects your production.` would be the most logical reason.

Comment: I must confess that I don't get it completely. I mean, the reason of needing Nginx and why Tornado itself isn't suitable for web serving in a production enviroment. Thanks a lot 'user' for answering. I don't get how this question can be marked as off-topic. As I see is extremely related to infraestructure.